# Is there a cellular physiological response to desiccation in animals?

Tags: physiology, marine-biology

There has been much research on the molecular effects of high levels of temperature for animals, specifically regarding heat shock proteins, protein denaturing and energy investment into stress tolerance.

I understand generally, the effects of desiccation with respect to the importance of moisture, specifically for aquatic animals (eg. oxygen uptake), but I can't seem to find much information on cellular-level responses to desiccation stress.

Are there are well established effects of desiccation on a cellular level or if there is a physiological response in the cell (eg. production of hsp)?

Comment: Try a search on Google Scholar for "cellular response to desiccation" - you might also try "cellular response to dehydration" or to "hyperosmotic stress."

Comment: I have searched Google Scholar extensively and found most research is on plants and algae. There is a bit on *Drosophila* , it seems sometimes desiccation results in hsp production but I've been reading up on but I'm pretty much stuck here.

Comment: What about my suggestions to look at dehydration or hyperosmolarity? I'm not exactly sure what's out there because I am more familiar with organism-level reactions to water stress rather than cellular adaptations but with 70,000 some results (although I agree, it looks like a lot of work on plants, which is why I was suggesting those other search terms) I'd expect you to find something in there.

Comment: Your over thinking it, search "Osmoregulation animal cells" here is two results. http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.ph.43.030181.002425?journalCode=physiol And  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21739/

Comment: @BryanKrause "Hyperosmotic stress" has been effective as has "cellular response to desiccation". I think I was over-thinking it John.

Comment: What's protocol now, should I delete the OP